# Script for comparing two files and outputs matching values

Tags: bash, perl

I am looking for a script for comparing two tab-delimited text files and outputs matching value.

I used this bash script but it gives only unique values (in other words, it does not work for such purpose)

```
grep -FwF file_1.txt file_2.txt > out.txt
```

#### File_1.txt

```
ref|apple.1| 
ref|apple.1| 
ref|apple.1| 
ref|peach.1| 
ref|peach.1|
ref|peach.1|
ref|fig.1| 
ref|pear.1| 
ref|pear.1| 
ref|apricot.1| 
ref|plum.1| 
ref|grape.1|
ref|grape.1| 
ref|grape.1| 
ref|grape.1|
```

#### File_2.txt

```
ref|apple.1|   prepared_for_goats
ref|peach.1|   prepared_for_tucans
ref|fig.1| prepared_for_piegons
ref|pear.1|    prepared for_pigs
ref|apricot.1| prepared_for_sheep
ref|plum.1|    prepared_for_gorilla 
ref|grape.1|   prepared_for_monkeys
```

#### Expected_Output

```
ref|apple.1|   prepared_for_goats
ref|apple.1|   prepared_for_goats
ref|apple.1|   prepared_for_goats
ref|peach.1|   prepared_for_tucans
ref|peach.1|   prepared_for_tucans
ref|peach.1|   prepared_for_tucans
ref|fig.1| prepared_for_piegons     
ref|pear.1| prepared for_pigs 
ref|pear.1|    prepared for_pigs
ref|apricot.1| prepared_for_sheep
ref|plum.1|    prepared_for_gorilla 
ref|grape.1|   prepared_for_monkeys
ref|grape.1|   prepared_for_monkeys
ref|grape.1|   prepared_for_monkeys
ref|grape.1|   prepared_for_monkeys
```

Comment: Maybe `diff` will work?

Comment: This is the wrong place to look for a script. This is a place to look for help writing a script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grep` won't do what you want.  `grep` is excels at selecting text but it is not good at mixing and merging.  By contrast, `awk` is designed for this task:

```
$ awk -F'|' 'FNR==NR{a[$1,$2]=$3; next} {print $1,$2,a[$1,$2]}' OFS='|'  file2 file1
ref|apple.1| prepared_for_goats 
ref|apple.1| prepared_for_goats 
ref|apple.1| prepared_for_goats 
ref|peach.1| prepared_for_tucans 
ref|peach.1| prepared_for_tucans 
ref|peach.1| prepared_for_tucans 
ref|fig.1| prepared_for_piegons 
ref|pear.1| prepared for_pigs 
ref|pear.1| prepared for_pigs 
ref|apricot.1| prepared_for_sheep 
ref|plum.1| prepared_for_gorilla 
ref|grape.1| prepared_for_monkeys
ref|grape.1| prepared_for_monkeys
ref|grape.1| prepared_for_monkeys
ref|grape.1| prepared_for_monkeys
```

(The test of the question said that the fields were tab-separated but the sample files showed `|` as the separator.  Since the SO editor does not clearly show tabs, I kept the `|` as the separator for this demonstration code.)

#### How it works

- `-F'|'`

  Set the field separator on *input* to `|`.
- `FNR==NR{a[$1,$2]=$3; next}`

  Due to the condition `FNR==NR`, this is only executed for the first file, `file2`.  For that file, we create associate array `a` which stores the third field, `$3`, under the key of the first two fields, `$1,$2`.
- `print $1,$2,a[$1,$2]`

  If we get here are are working on the second file, file1.  In that case, we print the first field, the second field, and the value of `a` that corresponds to those two fields.
- `OFS='|'`

  This sets the field separator on *output* to `|`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `join` *(the first field is used by default)*:

```
join file1 file2
```